# Why Certificate mismatch error in my PC and Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999? How it working in other mac browsers?

Tags: ios, ssl, https, dns, ssl-certificate

I have my secured web service let's say *https://myappdomain.com/appname/webservicename*
Above web-service, I used to get data from my server. I consumed this web service in my iOS application. It working for so long time. But today when I run application in my simulator then i got following error,

```
2021-07-16 21:23:37.864810+0530 PiBiAdmin[3597:71617] Task <6085DBEE-4CF2-4E62-AE76-1CF89F981F52>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myappdomain.com/appname.svc/webservicename, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myappdomain.com/appname.svc/webservicename, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <6085DBEE-4CF2-4E62-AE76-1CF89F981F52>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <6085DBEE-4CF2-4E62-AE76-1CF89F981F52>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
```

My code is in `Objective-C` and I used `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

When I cross verify my web service in chrome or safari browser I got an error `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

[image]

It same error I got in the safari browser. The interesting thing is same URL working in other windows and mac systems.
Also, issue when I create `ipa` file and sent it to the client. The client tells me the application not working. So this certificate mismatch error giving trouble in the client's ios device too.

How I resolved the mismatch issue? How I remove `*.footprintdns.com` certificate in my mac. I already removed such a certificate from keychain now it not showing me anything in the keychain.

My iOS app plist setting,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Even I tried set specific domain setting in my plist but didn't worked,

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>myappdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The very strange issue I facing right now.

Comment: The host name you use to connect to the server must match *.footprintdns.com. That part is pretty simple.

Comment: footprintdns.com isn't my domain name. If you see my screenshot .. I mention that and denoting my arrow. @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: Yes, that's your problem. There is no way around this, the host name you use to connect to the server must match one of the names in certificate, that's how SSL works. If the name of your server is example.com then example.com has to be one of the names in the certificate. In the example you are showing doesn't allow a host name of footprintdns.com, it only allows host names of the form *.footprintdns.com. There has to be a name component before footprintdns.com